# How to add column data in bulk?

Tags: import, column-data

I have a new SP 2007 site which I have been loading about a terabyte of files into.  File types include .doc, .docx, .ppt, .pptx, .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm, .jpg, .gif, .pdf.

What I need to do is add custom metadata for each file.  Fields include project name and department.  Since there are a large number of files, adding the data manually isn't an option.

How could I add it in bulk?

Comment: thank you for the answers! I have to put my testing on hold as we are now upgrading to 2010.  I will revisit this in a couple of weeks.  Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple console application that would do it for you through the SharePoint Object Model.  You could also do it with PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

There are several third party tools that let you do bulk import and bulk metadata setting, with some automation, including DocKIT, RoboMETA, and Classifier.

Since you are adding metadata and importing a very large number of documents, do you really want to put them all in the same document library?  There is a limit in 2007.  You might look into in the routing capability of the Records Center site template in SharePoint 2007, or move to SharePoint 2010 and use the more flexible Content Organizer or the metadata navigation features.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Web Services, you can use UpdateListItem
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Console is better for 1 TB

Answer (score 0):

you could import the metadata dorectly using a metadata file. Get the sample file from the metadata service application itself.