# CSV bulk file migration; additional columns for meta data

Tags: migration, content-migration, csv, document-migration

Similar to this  [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219057/migrate-files-and-metadata)  I have a number of local files, with associated metadata in an Excel sheet, that I would like to migrate to SharePoint. With inspiration from Microsofts own article on  [bulk CSV migration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-format-your-csv-file-for-data-content-migration)  I thought that perhaps this way the way to achieve my goals. So, does anyone know if it would be possible to extend the CSV file with the metadata that I would like to add and feed it to the SharePoint migration tool?

As this is a one off migration I do not really have the time to learn powershell or the funds to invest in, and learn to use, specialized software like suggested in the below posts. :-(

[How to add column data in bulk?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9459/how-to-add-column-data-in-bulk)

[Migrate Documents from local drive into SharePoint with default metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245897/migrate-documents-from-local-drive-into-sharepoint-with-default-metadata)